# What is the difference in the file content of a .po and a .pot file?

Tags: php, translation, gettext, po

I would like to have the following process flow:

1. The programmer marks some entries in the source code as translatable
2. The programmer generates a template file (.pot if I understood it correctly)
3. The translator uses the template file to translate the strings. He never has to get any part of the code.

If a new string is added or an old string gets updated, a new template is generated and the translator can "update" his old translation. He should only need to review / translate the changed / new strings. The programmer should not have to do this updating-work.

At the moment I use poEdit and its updating function. I guess this entry in the .po-file gives poEdit the needed information:

```
"X-Poedit-Basepath: /var/www/community-chess\n"
```

But this makes it necessary to have to complete, latest source code. This means, the programmer has to do the first step of updating.

If I understood it correct, .pot-files are templates for .po-files. Is this just an empty (hence with no translated strings) .po-file? How can I create a .pot-file for a PHP-project on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have i18n'd your source, you can [run `xgettext` against it](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#xgettext-Invocation) in order to extract all translatable strings into a .pot file.

Comment: I tried xgettext that way: `xgettext -D /var/www/community-chess/ login.wrapper.php `. As far as I know, I have to specify a single file. Only giving it the directory doesn't work. Additionaly it gives my a .po file which irritates me. This is the reason why I wanted to know if there is a difference in the file structure of .po and .pot.

Comment: No there is no structural difference between a PO and a POT file.  The POT is just an untranslated PO file that you use as a template.  In the workflow you want you would use xgettext as suggested and translators would update their PO files against POT.